# Android, API Server, and Firebase Database relation

Tags: android, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a project that I'm making which is An Android Application, which takes provides information taken from API Server (Laravel 5.x) and also provides live-chat feature

What I'm not sure of doing is how to handle the live-chat feature. Currently here's how the chat system works (keep in mind, there is also a Web App which provides the same feature, that I'm willing to change) :

1. User type chat and sends it. The client (Android app or Web App) sends it to the API Server. which then saves it to the database.
2. Then the API Server (which is connected to mysql database server) sends in email / notification which based on the other user's configuration.
3. When the other User opens the chat, it will call the API Server (which is connected to mysql database server) asking if there's an update every 3 seconds.
4. if there is, then (Android App or Web App) will show the new chat.

Now first of all I know that this is not efficient, bad on performance, etc.

Now I want to try and use firebase database for realtime chat.

Now, I really want to use the API Server for logging and storing Chat info inside my own database because of some legacy Android App which takes a long time to work on.

which is the better scenario :

1. The Android App directly sends new chat information to Firebase Database
2. The Android App sends new chat information to API Server. Then the API Server sends it to Firebase Database
3. Is there a better way to do this

so which is the better way to do this?

Comment: I'd probably use the API server for writing the information to the database, but have the clients connect directly to the database for reading/listening. This also saves you from the 3-second polling interval. But this type of choice is highly subjective, and very dependent on the exact details of your use-case. This makes it hard to answer correct on Stack Overflow: what is correct according to my experience, may be nonsense for your use-case. There is no one way that is better for everything.

Comment: I actually agree with your opinion. I actually wanted to do that. But I need opinion from others

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the firebase firestore. It sounds like it would solve the best of both worlds. Nosql json storage format is great for a chat app. Also the data is "live" so it will loosen for a change and update the user sides data. Saving you the 3 sec call resources. Last I checked it was still in beta but I used it top make an app that lets you create plus and live pools and it wad pretty smooth. It does take a bit to wrap your head around though.